# Не работает плагин Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Настроил всё так, как показано было в документации/сообществах/видеороликах, но при попытке отправки формы выдаёт это:
**"При отправке сообщения произошла ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте ещё раз позже."**
Позже попробовал взять такой же шаблон как в другом своём сайте, но и это не помогло, также попробовал выключить остальные плагины, но не помогло.
Как можно решить эту проблему? Или посоветуйте другой плагин с бесплатной возможностью добавления поля для телефона.(да, в форме есть всего лишь два поля - номер и имя.

Comment: См. логи. Может у тебя хостер запрещает отправку почту. В конструкторе форм ошибок нет? Проверь восстановление пароля - проходит нормально?

Comment: в конструкторе никаких красных звездочек, все вроде как настроено правильно, были мысли о хостинге... и в консоли админки пишет "Ваш сайт использует небезопасную версию PHP (5.6.40), её нужно обновить." Логи сейчас посмотрю

Comment: восстановление пароля хостинга или вордпресс?

Comment: включил и посмотрел логи, попробовал снова отправить форму, не получилось, а лог файл пустой

Comment: Естественно я про восстановление пароля ВП.

Comment: Логи ПОЧТЫ смотреть надо. И ОШИБОК php не помешает.

Comment: rest api не отключено часом?

Comment: Вопрос снят ребята, настриол wp mail SMTP, и заработало...

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос закрыт, пришлось в итоге использовать SMTP Mail и настроить через него почту, и тогда заработал contact form7

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/602157)

Comment: а где я дополнял вопрос?

Comment: тут вообще стоит решение а не какое то дополнение вопроса

Comment: у вас вопрос по contact-form7, какое отношение к нему имеет ваш "ответ"? думаю , замечание  @Spatz именно об этом

Comment: а в чем прикол открытых навсегда вопросов? наткнется кто нибудь уйдет ни с чем, а я дописал плагин, через которого потом начал нормально работать contact form

Comment: вместо того, чтобы не признавать чьи то помощи, идите в другие вопросы, займитесь чем то полезным